# Cabezera estática en documento HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Buenas tardes. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?
Quiero fijar la cabezera de la página, no importa si se abre el desplegable, debajo tiene que salir la cabezera. Sería algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sólo que mostrando otros datos en la cabezera.

Éste es mi código:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../css/nav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>

        #Label1
        {
            width:100%;
            font-size:100%;
        }
        #main-header {
    background: #333;
    color: white;
    height: 80px;

    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
}   
        #main-content {
    background: white;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

    #main-content header,
    #main-content .content {
        padding: 40px;
    }


    </style>
</head>
    <header id="main-header">
                    <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped " >
                        <tr>
                            <td >Solicitud</td>
                        </tr>
                       <tr>
                            <td>DNI</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nombre</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
    </header>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <table class="table table-striped " >
                        <tr>
                            <td >Solicitud</td>
                        </tr>
                       <tr>
                            <td>DNI</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Nombre</td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>Departamento</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <input id="Text1" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                     <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>Distrito</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <input id="Text2" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                     <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>  Urb/AAHH/Centro Poblado /Asoc. Vivienda</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text3" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>  Av/Calle/Jirón /Pasaje/Carretera/ Zona</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text4" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                     <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>  Sector/Grupo /Mz/Bloque/ Etapa</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text5" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>    Lote/Piso /Dpto/No.</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text6" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                     <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Referencia Ubicación</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text7" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                     <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Referencia fotográfica</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                     <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Tipo verificación</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text10" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>  inicio residencia</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text11" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                       <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Tipo verificación</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text12" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>Empresa/negocio</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text13" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                       <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>Recomendación Area de Ventas</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text14" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                       <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td>Canal/Agencia</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text15" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Fecha ingreso</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text16" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                      <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Segmento</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text17" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                     <table class="table table-striped ">
                        <tr class="success">
                            <td> Observación</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <input id="Text18" type="text" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Con bootstrap solo necesitas agregar la clase `navbar-fixed-top` y usar `<nav>` en lugar de `<header>`

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top"> 
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Boton Menu Collapsed</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
  <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li ><a href="#">Solicitud</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">DNI</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Nombre</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score -3):

CSS

`#main-content header{position: fixed; top: 0; }`

Comment: Por favor mejora tu respuesta. Lee: **[cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**.